# Is there a way to make denoising work in the Cycles viewport?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, denoise

I saw this in other renderers, such as the Radeon ProRender or V-Ray and was wondering if there's an Add-on or Build for Blender to work around the limitations of Cycles' Denoiser.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. From the [Official Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html) *Denoising* uses render tile information from the engine to make the necessary calculations for the image processing algorithm.

> Denoising filters the resulting image using information (known as
>   feature passes) gathered during rendering to get rid of noise, while
>   preserving visual detail as well as possible.
>
> To use the option, enable it in the render layers tab of the
>   Properties editor. On rendering, it will denoise tile by tile once all
>   the surrounding tiles are finished rendering.

It is not available for progressive renders, and as such doesn't work for viewport previews, which are a form of progressive render.

Comment: Thanks. I rephrased the question so I can hopefully still get denoising for the viewport :)