# How you denoise renderered images in Blender?

Tags: denoise, compositing-nodes

I am wanting to use Blender as a denoiser as well as a renderer, but I can't find how to bring an image in and denoise it in the compositor. I have tried using the despeckle node but I still can't seem to find the right way to do it.

Comment: Denoiser is only present in the latest versions of Blender. Enable it at the bottom of renderlayer settings tab.

Comment: **added comment as answer

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121118/is-there-a-way-to-make-denoising-work-in-the-cycles-viewport/121120#121120

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid noisy renders in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles)

Answer (score 3):

The Denoising Feature is only available for rendered images as it takes information from the unrendered scene as well as the pixel data of the rendered image to "guess" the right values of each pixel.

So unfortunately the denoiser isn't available for external images. There are a few compositing solutions available though. [Here](https://bwide.wordpress.com/node-groups/bwide-nodepack-for-blender/) are some node groups you can use.

Comment: Your link seems broken

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the URL in your link, since as @DuarteFarrajotaRamo pointed out, it seemed broken. If I made a mistake, please edit in the correct URL.